# SQL Date Format 107 Without Leading Zeros For The Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am needing to convert a date/time stamp via SQL to the following format:
**April 4, 2016**

Using

```
SELECT 
DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + 
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [PaymentDate]
```

gets me almost what I need, however, it puts a leading 0 on the day, leaving me with: 
`April 04, 2016`

How can I get rid of that leading 0 on the day?

Comment: What is your DBMS and version number?  From the format it looks like SQL Server?  If so, what version?

Comment: you can get the day by using `CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()))` but then you need another function for the year `CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()))`  if you are using sql 2012+ you can use `CONCAT` to combine the values without converting to varchars `CONCAT(DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()), ' ',DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), ', ', DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()))`

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am currently working in SQL Server. You did resolve my issue with the FORMAT() function. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, if you are using `SQL Server 2012` or later, you can use the [`FORMAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function for this:

```
Select Format(GetDate(), 'MMMM d, yyyy')
```

> April 4, 2016

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

QUERY:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE())+' '+DATENAME(dd, GETDATE())+' '+DATENAME(yy, GETDATE()) AS [PaymentDate];
```

RESULT:

[image]